# Creating reusable function in Google AdWords

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I'm currently writing a script in Google AdWords, and I'm managing lots of campaigns that use the same function (which I have had to copy-paste around 90+ times). Whenever I want to edit this function it becomes incredibly hard as I need to manually to through every script individually.

Is there any way of creating a reusable function, store it as a separate script and call it from AdWords like how I can call `Logger` and `DriveApp`? I've tried to use the following resources, which has been pretty useless so far:

- **[Standalone Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)** - Google somehow allows you to create scripts but not execute them from within AdWords (at least that's as far as I've managed to come)
- **[Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api)** - Gave up after getting constant 'Unauthenticated' errors (even when setting the permissions to 'Anyone, even anonymous')
- **[MCC Scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/examples/mcc-scripts)** - This allows me to update all accounts, but doesn't do what I need

If anyone knows any way of simply storing a function somewhere and calling it within Google AdWords, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your function a save it in a Google Drive file and the use it from there:

```
var scriptFile = getFile(location);
var scriptText = scriptFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
eval(scriptText);
```

Comment: Isn't eval considered dangerous?

Comment: Maybe... I have heard that sometimes but I use it all the time, and I have seen it used many times too...

Comment: eval is dangerous if you are evaling user supplied code or can't cryptographically secure your code in transit.  You can eval code you have written yourself that hasn't been tampered with.